# classify tweets using NLTK Python

Tags: python, twitter, nltk, sentiment-analysis

is there something we can do to classify the tweets using twitter_samples into : positive , negative ,and neutral , because I found just two files

```
positive_tweets = twitter_samples.strings('positive_tweets.json')
negative_tweets = twitter_samples.strings('negative_tweets.json')
```

so how can we get score from

```
NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_data).classify()
```

to classify to another category **neutral**

Comment: naive bayes is a supervised algorithm. So, in case you're planning to classify tweets into `n` different categories, in your training data you need to have `n` different labels. Using only positive and negative tweets in your training data there's no way to predict a neutral category.

Comment: I solve this problem but the next challenge is to how to raise the accuracy of the classifier... I take 400k comments(training set) and never gets above 50%